# Make TestExecutionListener skip/ignore a test

Tags: spring, junit

I'm currently using a Spring TestExecutionListener to process custom annotations within my test classes. Dependend on some outside circumstances I'd like to ignore a test.

Currently I'm using a Assume within the `beforeTestClass` or `beforeTestMethod` to achive this, which works. But unfortunately it creates a warning in the log includeding a stacktrace which is far to noisy.

Is it somehow possible to ignore the test programmatically (maybe using the TestContext)?

Comment: Can't you just add `@ActiveProfiles( profiles={"dev"}` for the test and switch on off profiles?

Comment: Due to complex hardware requirements that's not possible without getting to complex. Therefore we created our own Annotations to skip tests depending on the attached devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try extending the default test runner and provide a custom implementation of the `isIgnored` method:

```
public class CustomRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {
    public CustomRunner(Class<?> c) throws initializationError {
        super(c);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isIgnored(FrameworkMethod child) {
        if(shouldIgnore()) {
           return true;
        }
        return super.isIgnored(child);
    }

    private boolean shouldIgnore() {
        /* some custom criteria */
    }
}
```

Here, the [base implementation](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.html#isIgnored(org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod)) ignores tests that have the `@Ignore` annotation, but you can provide your own implementation of the ignore criteria.